# Creating an attached property

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I am want to study how to create a simple attached property.  For example, to rotate figure on the canvas.  Something like this, but using attached property:

```
    <Canvas Margin="0 200">
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="60"
                 RenderTransformOrigin=".5, .5">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="30"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
```

I have created class:

```
class RotationManager : DependencyObject
{
    public static double GetAngle(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double) obj.GetValue(AngleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAngle(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AngleProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnAngleChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = obj as UIElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.RenderTransformOrigin= new Point(.5, .5);
            var transform = new RotateTransform();
            transform.Angle = (double) e.NewValue;
            element.RenderTransform = transform;

        }                
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Angle",
            typeof (double), typeof (RotationManager),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnAngleChanged));
}
```

And modified my XAML:

```
  <Canvas Margin="0 200">
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="60" 
                 local:RotationManager.Angle="45"/>
 </Canvas>
```

But if I will add `local:RotationManager.Angle="45"` the ellipse disappear from canvas.  Why ?
I set the breakpoints to my RotationManager, but no one of the method executes.

How can I fix it?

Comment: No time to test, so I'll put it as a comment, but you probably need to specify CenterX and CenterY of the transform.

Comment: @demas Just a note, class `RotationManager` does not need to be derived from DependencyObject, as long as it does not declare any non-attached dependency properties.

Comment: @Clemens, are you testing with windows-8.1 modern app?

Comment: No, you have tagged your question WPF, so i'm testing with a WPF application. Windows Store Apps don't use WPF. But I'll try...

Comment: @Clemens, thanks. I didn't know it. I think that windows 8.1 uses subset of WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in Windows Runtime the class needs to be public:

```
public class RotationManager
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how did you get it?

Comment: Got an exception saying "Failed to assign to property 'RotationManager.Angle'".